# Phrygian creation myth

Tags: creation

Years ago I heard that the Phrygians had, in their creation myth, that they were the firstborn people of creation.

This came up in the context of biblical studies where the apostle Paul - in his letter to Colossae, which is in Phrygian territory - uses the metaphor of "firstborn of all creation" about Jesus. The speaker noted that Paul is probably using that metaphor in that letter because of the cultural context.

I was recently researching Phrygian creation myths but could not find anything that detailed. Does anyone have any ideas where I might look to find this? Thanks

Comment: I apologise for dragging this question back up. I have removed my answer because i made a catastrophic error. I was originally going to answer your question, so i began typing, but then decided to move to another question in a seperate window, without closing this one. But i went to another window after that and came back to what i thought was the correct window, and i wrote an answer to your question that was supposed to be the answer to the other question in other window. I noticed the error after around 12 hours had passed. Apologies. Thought i should let you know

Comment: No worries!  Have a great day!

Answer (score 2):

I found my own answer.

It comes from Herodotus, Histories, Book 2, v 1. He is discussing which people were the oldest on the earth.

Here is the quote - "Now before Psammetichus became king of Egypt,1 the Egyptians believed that they were the oldest people on earth. But ever since Psammetichus became king and wished to find out which people were the oldest, they have believed that the **Phrygians** were older than they, and they than everybody else."

Both Paul in his letter to Colossae and John in the letter to Laodicea (from Revelation) refer to "firstborn" or "ruler of God's creation" which was supposed to be Adam.

Both Colossae and Laodicea are Phrygian cities.

Here is a link: http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.01.0126%3Abook%3D2%3Achapter%3D2